# necessary and sufficient condition for purely imaginary generalized eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues

Consider the generalized eigenvalue equation
$$A \mathbf{v}=\lambda S \mathbf{v}$$
where $S$ is a real square symmetric matrix and $A$ a real square anti-symmetric matrix.

I seek a necessary and sufficient condition for the eigenvalues $\lambda$ to be purely imaginary.

*sufficient* conditions include

- $S$ is positive definite
- $S$ is negative definite
- $S$ and $A$ commute, and $S$ is invertible

That none of these are necessary is shown by this example
$$S=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & -2 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$\lambda=0,\pm i\sqrt{3}$$

On the other hand, symmetry of $S$ and anti-symmetry of $A$ does not suffice, even if $S$ is invertible and diagonalizable
$$S=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 6 & 4 & 10 \\
 4 & 12 & 4 \\
 10 & 4 & 12 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 7 & 3 \\
 -7 & 0 & -1 \\
 -3 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$|A-\lambda S|=0\implies 304 \lambda^3-418 \lambda =0\implies \lambda=0,\pm \frac{\sqrt{\frac{11}{2}}}{2}$$
In this case, all eigenvectors have $<v,S v>=0$ and $<v,A v>=0$, but $S v$ and $A v$ themselves are not both $0$: the eigenvalue problem remains well-defined.

Comment: Don't we just always have $(Av,v)\in i\mathbb R$ and $(Sv,v)\in \mathbb R$, so the only danger is that we directly hit the surface $(Sv,v)=0$ in which case we must also have $(Av,v)=0$ and we cannot obtain the result by passing to the limit from a generic position, so everything smells of degeneracy? In other words, do you have an example when it is not the case and the generalized eigenvalue problem is still meaningful?

Comment: @fedja Yes, I edited in such an example. If $S$ is indefinite, there are nonzero $v$ with nonzero $S v$ such that $<v,S v>=0$.

Comment: @fedja Your comment does suggest a useful answer: there must be no simultaneous nonzero solutions of $<v,A v>=0$ and $<v, S v>=0$